# Python Regex for Double decimal place number (maybe negative) not preceded by a string

Tags: python, regex

So I am trying to develop a python Regex that can capture an exactly double decimal placed number that is not preceded by the specific string: "JPY". Here are some examples:

**Matches:**

- 100.00
- 12.00
- 2.30
- -10000.12

**Nonmatches (that might exist):**

- 2.01212331
- JPY 123.00
- JPY 10000.12

I had this expression: `(-?\d+\.\d\d(?!\d))`. Basically it works by matching a string that:

1. Optionally starts with a negative: `-?`
2. Contains at least one digit: `\d+`
3. Then a Decimal Place Period: `\.`
4. Then exactly two numbers: `\d\d`
5. And if you find that there are any more digits after, ignore that match `(?!\d)`

But then as soon as I wanted to add the currency negative look-behind, it fails: `(?<!JPY )(-?\d+\.\d\d(?!\d))`.

The reason why this happens somewhat makes sense to me, but I still don't like it. Basically, for a string like: `JPY 1600.00`, it ends up discarding `JPY 1` and considers `600.00` a match. But the thing is, that doesn't make sense. `1` is not a valid match to be discarded because of the preceding `JPY` . So what is going on?

---

Funnily enough [this website](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookbehind-assertions.php) which was the second Google result for "Negative Lookbehind" has this exact same example, but they don't use matching groups. I need the matching groups because I'm trying to extract the number.

---

The same logic of discarding the whole match works with the lookahead (#5 above) but doesn't work with this lookbehind. Why? I've tried moving that inside and outside the matching group but nothing works.

This seems like just a tiny bug to fix but I'm very tired and I've tried a lot of variations and nothing works. Any guidance appreciated!

---

@AlexanderMashin's full solution (that works):

`((?<!JPY )(?<!\d)-?\d+\.\d\d(?!\d))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two other negative lookbehind assertions: `(?<!\d)(?<!-)` as in https://regex101.com/r/kiFIPx/1 (`(?<!JPY )(?<!\d)(?<!-)(-?\d+\.\d\d(?!\d))`).

The first assertion `(?<!\d)` will make sure that there are no digits before the matched number. The second assertion `(?<!-)`will prevent matching `10000.12` in `JPY -10000.12`.

Comment: PS. I accidentally deleted that regex URL, so I'll update the post to reflect your full RegEx Solution

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Watch out, if there are more than one space between `JPY` and the number, you [will get unwanted matches](https://regex101.com/r/kiFIPx/2). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151360/3832970) is a good solution that can be extended to work even in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<!JPY )(-?\d+\.\d\d(?!\d))` won't match `1600.00` in `JPY 1600.00` because:

1. If it would match `1600.00`, the characters precede them are `JPY`  and they would match `(?<!JPY )`. Because `(?<!...)` is `**Negative Lookbehind**` so it won't allow the match. Therefore `1600.00` could not be a match.
2. If it would match `600.00`, 4 characters precede them are `PY 1` and they would not match `(?<!JPY )`. So `600.00` is a valid match.

If you want a regex that match `1600.00`, @alexander had propose a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also get the matches without using any lookarounds by matching what you don't want and capture what you want to keep.

```
\bJPY\s*-?\d+\.\d+|(-?\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d))
```

**Explanation**

- `\bJPY\s*-?\d+\.\d+` The pattern for the match that you don't want
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `-?\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d)` Match optional `-`, 1+ digits, a dot and 2 digits
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMhC9L/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gkLRxe)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\bJPY\s*-?\d+\.\d+|(-?\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d))"

test_str = ("100.00\n"
    "12.00\n"
    "2.30\n"
    "-10000.12\n"
    "2.01212331\n"
    "JPY 123.00\n"
    "JPY 10000.12\n"
    "JPY -10000.12\n"
    "JPY  123.00\n"
    "JPY  10000.12\n"
    "JPY  -10000.12")

print(list(filter(None, re.findall(regex, test_str))))
```

Output

```
['100.00', '12.00', '2.30', '-10000.12']
```

Comment: I'd [change the first space to `\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/JMhC9L/2) to make sure no match is found even if there are more spaces between `JPY` and the number.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin See the update after the suggestion of Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Strangely, the regex demo shows results different from the Python demo. The regex demo matches what it should't (without captures).

Comment: @AlexanderMashin That is correct, the pattern matches what you don't want, then captures in a group what you want to keep. [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns the values of the capturing group.

Comment: OK. Is see it now.